# Import css file into component

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-bootstrap and I need to import one css file into my component, like this:

> Load it from node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css
>   via package bundler like Angular CLI, if you're using one.

(this is on component's documentation).

I don't know how to load the bs-datepicker.css via package bundler.

**What I have tried is:**

- On my component, I tried to load:

`styleUrls: ['node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css']`

(no success, this wasn't found).

The file is in this directory:

`C:\DEV\senai-5s-webapp\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\datepicker\bs-datepicker.css`

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: Yes, I am using! @David

Answer (score 7):

In your `.angular-cli.json` file, modify the style property to add the css file besides your other styles (you should already have `styles.css` by default)

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can import them to in your `.angular-cli.json` here

```
  "styles": [
        "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css,
         ...
      ],
```

Comment: Usually there is no need for view encapsulation, if the styles are not overlapping.

Comment: Yes, Encapsulation.None means that the component styles will leak to child elements Here, styles are applied at the application level, so there is no need for that